# Ubuntu 16.04. Как понять, насколько занята RAM?

Tags: ubuntu

Всем привет. Купил VPS на ubuntu 16.04, 1GB RAM, процессор 2x2400. Поставил туда apache2, php, mysql, redis. Нагрузка на сервер мизерная - 200 юзеров/4000 хитов в сутки. При этом, график monitorix показывает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тот пик, где было 1.0, я знаю из-за чего был, там я виноват. Но нормальна ли такая ситуация при таком стеке и нагрузках? И что означает cached блок на этом графике?

Comment: cached используется ядром линукса для своих нужд, например для хранения часто используемых файлов, чтобы не перечитывать их постоянно с жёсткого диска. Когда приложения занимают много памяти, cached освобождается, поэтому можно считать cached свободной памятью

Comment: Возможно, в пике вы интенсивно работали с файловой системой и линукс активно кэшировал её, это вроде ничего страшного

Comment: у вопроса в данной формулировке нет ответа. нужна расшифровка: 1. слова «занята». 2. слов «active» и «inactive» на рисунке (раз он является ключевым, что вообще-то не очень хорошо для вопроса на этом сайте).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin подозреваю, автор об этом и спрашивает)

Comment: @andreymal, если речь про второй пункт, то автору можно порекомендовать читать документацию к той поделке, которая это нарисовала. ибо в `$ man free` таких слов вообще нет. а если про первый, то полный «расклад» понятия «занято» (относительно оперативной памяти) потянет на небольшую книжку.